# display dropdown values with optgroup option name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown grouped lists (Optgroup).  Need to display the values from second optgroup based on selected value in the first optgroup from below the dropdown.

```js
const needle = '[DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS]';
// using jQuery:
$('select option').prop('disabled', function() {
  return this.text.includes(needle);
});

$("#caption_collection").change(function() {
  $('#selected').html(' ');
  $("#caption_collection option:selected").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.length) {
      var selText = $this.text();
      console.log(selText);
      $('#selected').append(selText + ', ');
      //$('#selected').text('Only Captions allowed are:').append(selText + ', ');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" size=20 id="caption_collection">

  <optgroup label="MAKE A CHOICE">
    <option>ALLOW SELECT HERE</option>
    <option>DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS</option>
    <option>SHOW ALL LISTED CAPTIONS</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="ELSE SELECT ONE OR MULTIPLE">
    <option>ALWCaption-A100104 [ALLOW SELECT HERE]</option>
    <option>ZSDCaption-Z100104 [ALLOW SELECT HERE]</option>
    <option>XCDCaption-S100104 [ALLOW SELECT HERE]</option>
    <option>DCVCaption-Q100104 [ALLOW SELECT HERE]</option>
    <option>ERTCaption-D100104 [ALLOW SELECT HERE]</option>
    <option>BNMCaption-XX223366 [DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS]</option>
    <option>XWECaption-XX243356 [DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS]</option>
    <option>QWECaption-XX323356 [DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS]</option>
    <option>DFGCaption-XX228866 [DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS]</option>
    <option>TYUCaption-XX220066 [DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS]</option>
    <option>POICaption-XX423366 [DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS]</option>
    <option>GHJCaption-D100104 [ALLOW SELECT HERE]</option>
    <option>LKICaption-D100104 [ALLOW SELECT HERE]</option>
    <option>UYTCaption-XX423366 [DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS]</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>
<br><br>
<div>
  <textarea id="selected" rows="4" cols="56" readonly></textarea>
</div>
```

Got 3 options under first optgroup ""MAKE A CHOICE" as below

```
ALLOW SELECT HERE
DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS
SHOW ALL LISTED CAPTIONS
```

What i want is clicking on each get me the value in my textarea as:

On Select of -> ALLOW SELECT HERE

```
     A100104  ,Z100104  ,S100104  ,Q100104  ,D100104  ,D100104  ,D100104
```

On Select of -> DO NOT ALLOW SELECT FOR THIS

```
     XX223366  ,XX243356  ,XX323356  ,XX228866  ,XX220066  ,XX423366  ,XX423366
```

On Select of -> SHOW ALL LISTED CAPTIONS

```
    XX223366  ,XX243356  ,XX323356  ,XX228866  ,XX220066  ,XX423366  ,XX423366, A100104  ,Z100104  ,S100104  ,Q100104  ,D100104  ,D100104  ,D100104
```

AND under optgroup label="ELSE SELECT ONE OR MULTIPLE" need to display one or more value as :

```
A100104  ,Z100104  ,S100104
A100104
```

Though I can extract

```
var stre = "LKICaption-D100104  [ALLOW SELECT HERE]"
var str2 = stre.split('-');
var strval = str2[str2.length - 1];
//alert(strval) // D100104  [ALLOW SELECT HERE]

alert(strval.split(' ')[0]) // Worked this way o/p is D100104
```

or let me know if this is not the correct way to design and get the desired outcome, I will work according to any other design suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand but, you can add `value` attribute to each `option` tag and set the value to whatever you need. Then, grab the data: https://jsbin.com/veguye/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Actually each of the option are dynamic and coming from a function after parsing file which and all the values are displayed in dropdown after that. I just used an example for my problem statement here.

Comment: No problem. You can set the `value` attribute dynamically. Isn't?